# PCI passthrough: vfio-pci ignores ids of devices

Tags: virtual-machine, kernel-modules, gpu, pci

I have 3 GPUs in my dual XEON server.

I followed [instructions on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) and set up `vfio-pci` with `ids=10de:100c,10de:0e1a`:

```
$ modprobe -c | grep vfio
options vfio_iommu_type1 allow_unsafe_interrupts=1
options vfio_pci ids=10de:100c,10de:0e1a
...
```

But according to `dmesg` vfio ignores that option:

```
[    1.278976] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[    1.306193] vfio_pci: add [1002:7142[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[    1.326139] vfio_pci: add [1002:7162[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
```

Moreover when I unplugged card with `1002:7142` and `1002:7162` devices on-board and reboot I still have such entries in `dmesg` output and no more!

I upgraded linux kernel version and `vfio_pci` started to add another card but still independent in `ids` option!

I don't know what to do to resolve that problem. I want to setup certain GPU to be add as `vfio_pci` device. I don't even know where to look.

List of GPUs:

```
#IOMMU group 17
#  02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X] [1002 :6798]
#  02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series] [1002:aaa0]
#IOMMU group 18
#  03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK110B [GeForce GTX TITAN Black] [10de:100c] (rev a1)
#  03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 HDMI Audio [10de:0e1a] (rev a1)
#IOMMU group 30
#  83:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515 PRO [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] [1002:7142]
#  83:00.1 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515 PRO [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] (Secondary) [1002:7162]
```

Modprobe settings:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
options vfio-pci ids=10de:100c,10de:0e1a
```

Linux version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 4.4.21-1-lts #1 SMP Thu Sep 15 20:38:36 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `lspci -s 02:00.0 -vk` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to put it to grub :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt vfio-pci.ids=10de:100c,10de:0e1a"
```

try to put it to vfio.conf:

```
#softdep radeon pre: vfio-pci
#softdep amdgpu pre: vfio-pci
softdep snd_hda_intel pre: vfio-pci
softdep nouveau pre: vfio-pci
softdep nvidia pre: vfio-pci
#softdep drm pre: vfio-pci
#softdep xhci_hdc pre: vfio-pci
#options kvm_amd avic=1
```

and then update your boot seq ...

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```